# Black screen when entering password for system partition encryption (nvidia)

Tags: nvidia, encryption

I'm with nvidia driver and system partition encryption set during installation. While I was with the default open source driver the password screen for the decryption was appearing fine. As soon as I switched to the latest nvidia driver from the app centre the screen where I enter this pass is all black and I have to enter the password in the dark and when it gets to the login screen is the first time when I have picture. 
I was lucky to actually find out it's like that.

So, any easy way to fix this?