# Unable to enter passphrase for encyrtion - screen looks weird

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, encryption

I have two PCs with encrypted / (home is not separated) partitions.

On both i struggle with entering my pass phrase to decrypt the /.

One PC has an ATI VGA card with the default driver and the screen turns black after the GRUB menu. But if I press any key from the "Delete-block" of the keyboard I see (a command line alike) prompt for entering the pass phrase with already three starts in it (that i have to delete).
Like mentioned in this article:
[Black screen when entering password for system partition encryption (nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517920/black-screen-when-entering-password-for-system-partition-encryption-nvidia)
Is there a way to get the prompt without pressing delete?

Even more annoying is decrypting the / partition on my laptop with NVIDIA graphics and driver:
Before I installed the driver the issue was the same. But now It seams to load the decryption screen but it looks very weird (see first image).
I remember the decryption screen used to look like this on Ubuntu 14.04 (fitting the screen size and working on both PCs) but with versions 14.10 and 15.04 I experience this issues (Hardware has not changed only installed the newer versions freshly - no upgrade).
I am not able to type anything into that. I can only reboot by pressing Control-ALT-DEL.
After I press Control-Alt-Del and after leaving the GRUB menu a second time for Ubuntu I immediately receive a pass phrase prompt (see second image).
There I can enter my pass phrase and ubuntu starts.

I would be grateful, if somebody could show me how do get the pass phrase prompt immediately. I don't care about a fancy boot screen, a terminal alike would be fine (and would look way cooler).
Is there any way to tell ubuntu to give me this terminal alike pass phrase prompt on both systems (or like on the second image)?

---

Unfortunately I am not allowed to post images there fore I uploaded them somewhere else:

first image:
http://www.redkid.net/hostimage/images/23662567024242605804.jpg

second image:
http://www.redkid.net/hostimage/images/72993887678194098690.jpg